# Print to file used jars in an eclipse maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have multi module maven eclipse project, so i was wondering if its possible to get all the libraries that are imported in the project  and have them in some txt file, so I can write some documentation about project etc. So basically what I am asking is if someone knows how to export all the libraries that are listed when you go Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries(tab) and then Maven Dependencies...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do it in code, however there are a couple of options for generating a text file.

1. Take a look at [Class Dependency Analyzer](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/). Useful tool for generating a list of dependencies.
2. You could use the maven dependency tree to generate the text file content, see more [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html):

   ```
   $ mvn dependency:tree
   ```

Comment: 2nd option did the job :  mvn dependency:tree -DoutputFile=my_libs.txt 
tnx